# Using Postgres row_to_json() function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

In Rails 4.x, I'm trying to figure out how to return JSON straight from Postgres, so I don't have a bunch of ActiveRecord objects (or hashes) returned, that I then need to hold in memory and serialize into JSON. Since Postgres can return JSON natively now as a result, it seems much better for writing a JSON API.

In Postgres, for a table called books I'd write something like:

```
select row_to_json(books) from books;
```

Normally, in Rails, I'd do something like `Book.all` to load them up, but I'd like to use that `row_to_json` function. How can I do this without just manually writing my SQL query?

Ideally, I'd do something like `Book.all.rows_to_json` to return a JSON string.

I do *not* want to do `render json: @books` as that's going to use the built-in parser, and load everything up at AR objects.

Comment: Have you tried to do `Book.select('row_to_json(books)')`?  I'm not sure what that will look like, since Rails will try to instantiate ActiveRecord objects with the result from Postgres.  If that doesn't work, try `Book.connection.execute('select row_to_json(books) from books')`.

Comment: Yea, i can manually do it with `#execute` but then I'm manually generating queries (which might be pretty deep and complex). Ideally, it would take the query generator, and reformat things to work with `row_to_json` no matter how deep it is, or if it has more complex logic/scopes/etc.

Comment: The most underrated question on stackoverflow for rails devs dealing with large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I also like fast endpoints and enjoy AR syntax

something like

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :rows_to_json, -> {
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
      <<~SQL.squish,
        SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(query))
        FROM (#{to_sql}) AS query
      SQL
    ).first["json_agg"] || [].to_json
  }
end
```

then

```
> Book.all.rows_to_json
SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(query)) FROM (SELECT "books".* FROM "books") AS query
=> "[{\"id\":\"123\"}]"
```

and the controller becomes

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Book.all.rows_to_json
  end
end
```

if there was any logic in the model's serializer, it will need to be ported to SQL:

```
Book.select(%q{author as "authorName"}).all.rows_to_json
```